# Como compartir contexto de un Fragment a un Adapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment, arrayadapter

Estoy intentando hacer un volcado de una base de datos (firebase) en un listview de dentro de un fragment para mostrarlo y que se actualice cuando alguien realiza una nueva inserción o borrado y demás. Pero me está dando problemas el adapter que le pasa los datos al listview, como que no le estoy poniendo correctamente el contexto  del fragment o así.

He probado poniendo el nombre del fragment y getContext(), pero pese a no resaltarme ningún error, la aplicación sigue sin poder ejecutarse.

Dejo el código:

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    lstvw = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lstvwlistamini);
    ddbbr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Juegos");
    ddbbr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot datasnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Juego juego =  datasnapshot.getValue(Juego.class);

                String titulo = juego.getTitulo();
                list.add(titulo);

            }
          //aquí es donde me da problemas
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
            lstvw.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    ...
}
```

Comment: revisa el erro del logcat para tener una idea de porque pasa eso

Comment: Me aparece esto:  
`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.prueba, PID: 6736
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucedes que no esta encontrando el Listview por lo tanto estas intentando asignarle el `adapter` a objeto null:

Si tu clase extiende de `Fragment` debes de inflar la vista:

```
View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.nombre_fragment, container, false);
```

Y despues buscar tu listview:

```
 lstvw = v.findViewById(R.id.lstvwlistamini);
```

Comment: ¡Funciona! muchas gracias, no era capaz de verlo
lo único que ahora por algún motivo no me muestra los datos... pero seguramente esté haciendo mal la referencia a la bbdd o similar

Comment: igual puedes revisar el logcat para ver el error

Comment: Vale, después de ver que tenía mal la referencia a la bbdd y que me faltaba el constructor por defecto en la clase "Juego" ahora solo me aparece `eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da`
creo que igualemente ahora solo falla la referencia a la bbdd así que voy a mirar más exhaustivamente a ver si lo resuelvo, gracias de nuevo